# Java libGDX disconnection from the camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In the game I got the text, hero and opponent. The camera `OrthographicCamera` is focused on a hero so text moves around the screen. Can somehow be disconnected text from the camera? To be in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Two Cameras** to achieve this easily. Keep one moving with the player, and keep one fixed to the screen.

Use the second one to draw only text.

---

Reference : [Multiple cameras in libgdx ( probably similar in other frameworks )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345783/multiple-cameras-in-libgdx-probably-similar-in-other-frameworks)

Hope this helps.