# Locking Text in Android Studio using Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I made a flappy bird clone and the pipes are going forward to the bird, but the text comes with the pipes. I want to lock the text in the middle of the screen.

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);

    sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x, bird.getPosition().y);
    for (Tube tube : tubes) {
        sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBotTube().x, tube.getPosBotTube().y);
    }
    sb.draw(ground, groundPos1.x, groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(ground, groundPos2.x, groundPos2.y);
    sb.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a `Scene2D` `Stage` with a static `Viewport` to display a hud or gui as a overlay on top of the actual game.

In most cases a HUD or GUI should be fixed to the actual screen and should not move therefor to have a movable camera in your game world you have to separate these elements entirely. What is happening in your case is that your current camera is drawing all elements and when it moves position the elements of your GUI will be drawn at a different position on your screen, like your "pipes" do.

If you are just drawing your text using the same batch an easy fix would be to just setup a new camera for this and when you are done drawing your game just input it's combined matrix to the projection matrix of the SpriteBatch, after you end it.

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(movingCam.combined);
spriteBatch.begin();
//... draw stuff that belongs to your game world
spriteBatch.end();

spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(staticCam.combined);
spriteBatch.begin();
//... draw stuff that belongs to your GUI
spriteBatch.end();
```

Anyway, I would still recommend using Scene2D for the purpose of a GUI since it has everything you would need like buttons, tables, labels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you moving the camera to follow the bird? Just use an extra camera for your UI and/or static texts like score counters. And draw them after drawing game objects (on top of them).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345783/multiple-cameras-in-libgdx-probably-similar-in-other-frameworks) and submitted answer.